# Today's dist-upgrade on Natty

Tags: 11.04, apt, package-management

Apt resulted few erronous lines on dist-upgrade.

```
Preparing to replace gir1.2-mutter-2.91 2.91.93-0ubuntu1~build1 (using .../gir1.2-mutter-2.91_3.0.0-0ubuntu1~build1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gir1.2-mutter-2.91 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-mutter-2.91_3.0.0-0ubuntu1~build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mutter/Meta-3.0.typelib', which is also in package gir1.2-mutter-3.0 3.0.0-0ubuntu1~build2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-mutter-2.91_3.0.0-0ubuntu1~build1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

NOTE. I have also installed gnome-shell, Other desktops (Unity, Classic) does not load and report error (Could not load ths session etc.)  on login time. So Using gnome-shell.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 11.04 is currently in Beta so things might not work right. Please [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the same file exists in two distinct packages: gir1.2-mutter-3.0 and gir1.2-mutter-2.91 (note these are package names without version numbers). You could:

1. Remove one of the packages, probably gir1.2-mutter-3.0. The downside is that this could force you to remove other packages that depend on it.
2. Install gir1.2-mutter-2.91 using `dpkg --force-overwrite`, which will overwrite the conflicting file. There is a small risk that this could cause problems, but you can always recover by reinstalling the old version.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that there's a bug filed about this.